# Линейный список: удаления

Tags: c++, список

Я создал линейный список. По http://pastebin.com/qUvX8FMt
Если посмотреть на код, то можно заметить, что функция `void erase_after(Node* x)` удаляет элемент списка после элемента `x`. А как мне сделать так, чтобы она удаляла элемент `x`? Не могу решить. Пробовал следующим образом:

```
if (x == begin()) {
        cout << "Удалить первый узел";
}
for (Node* i = begin(); i->next != end(); i=i->next) {
    Node* tmp = i->next;
    if (tmp && tmp == x) {
        i->next = i->next->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Но это приводит к поиску ошибки.
Возникла идея организовать двусвязный список, но я абсолютно не представляю себе как можно переписать тогда пример кода выше.

Comment: @huxi, из вопроса не виден прототип функции. Должно быть что-то вроде

     void delete_node (Node **list, Node *x) { // удалить x из list
        if (!x || !*list)
          return;
        if (*list == x) { // первый в списке
          *list = x->next;
          delete x;
        } else 
          for (Node *t = *list; t; t = t->next)
            if (t->next == x)
               return arase_after(t);
     }

В общем, поскольку удаляемый элемент может быть первым в списке, то нужно 2 параметра (удаляемый элемент и голова списка).

Comment: Удалось запустить, но возникла следующая проблема. После удаления елементов, не работает вывод елементов на екран (Поиск ошибки)

Comment: @huxi, Вы относящиеся к делу фрагменты кода и данных приведите, тогда посмотрим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[[[@huxi](/users/18181/huxi)](/users/18181/huxi)](/users/18181/huxi)](/users/18181/huxi), а у меня Ваш код вообще не компилируется.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ huxilist.cpp 
huxilist.cpp: In copy constructor ‘List::List(const List&)’:
huxilist.cpp:16:47: error: passing ‘const List’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘List::Node* List::begin()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
huxilist.cpp:16:60: error: passing ‘const List’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘List::Node* List::end()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
huxilist.cpp: In member function ‘List& List::operator=(const List&)’:
huxilist.cpp:37:27: error: passing ‘const List’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘List::Node* List::begin()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
huxilist.cpp:37:40: error: passing ‘const List’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘List::Node* List::end()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
huxilist.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
huxilist.cpp:114:9: error: ‘List_m’ has not been declared
huxilist.cpp:114:23: error: ‘it1’ was not declared in this scope
huxilist.cpp:114:29: error: ‘listfile’ was not declared in this scope
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Вы уж проверьте, что выложили.

**UPDATE**

[[[[@huxi](/users/18181/huxi)](/users/18181/huxi)](/users/18181/huxi)](/users/18181/huxi), тогда в комментарии я написал достаточно общую функцию удаления, работающую вообще вне какого-либо класса. Откровенно говоря, я не стал разбираться, в чем именно у Вас ошибка в реализации метода delete_node().

Вот такая реализация (применительно к Вашему классу List) вроде бы работает:

```
  int delete_node (Node *x) {
    if (!x || !head)
      return -1;
    if (x == head) {
      head = x->next;
      delete x;
      return 0;
    }
    for (Node *t = head; t; t = t->next)
      if (t->next == x) {
        t->next = x->next;
        delete x;
        return 0;
      }
    return -1; 
  }
```

Поскольку тут мы оперируем конкретным списком (его адресует поле head класса), то достаточно одного параметра.